# Grant workspace access for Datastore.register_azure_blob_container - Documentation?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

Is there any documentation on the `grant_workspace_access` parameter in the `Datastore.register_azure_blob_container` method? I see it called out in the [SDK documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.datastore(class)?view=azure-ml-py#register-azure-blob-container-workspace--datastore-name--container-name--account-name--sas-token-none--account-key-none--protocol-none--endpoint-none--overwrite-false--create-if-not-exists-false--skip-validation-false--grant-workspace-access-false--subscription-id-none--resource-group-none-), but I'm getting an error when I try to call the service and I don't know how to troubleshoot.

The error I'm getting is:

```
ERROR - Registering datastore failed with a 400 error code and error message 
'Cannot create resource using Workspace MSI access token. Please make sure Administrator/ 
User Access Administrator grants the Contributor RBAC role for the workspace.
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the documentation page contains documentation for that parameter.

`Grants Workspace Managed Identities (MSI) access to the user storage account, defaults to False. This should be set if the Storage account is in VNET. If set to True, we will use your identity to grant access to the user storage account. It may take a while for the granted access to reflect.`

Did you set the `grant_workspace_access` parameter to `True` when you register the datastore?

Comment: Yes. I set the parameter to True and got the error above. Like I said, I saw it listed on the SDK documentation, but I don’t know how to troubleshoot the error above.

Comment: Hi @Erik, sorry for the late reply. The error above is caused by the Workspace Managed Identity not having the correct roles assigned for the storage account. In the storage account's IAM section, please grant the Workspace Managed Identity with the Blob Data Owner and Contributor roles. The Workspace Managed Identity by default has the same name as the workspace. Please [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-portal) for a guide on how to update the IAM for storage account.